# Lightweight classes with specified fields in Python

Tags: python, class, namedtuple

I'm looking for something very like `namedtuples`:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Party = namedtuple('Party', ['guests', 'location'])
>>> p = Party(['Jed', 'Fred', 'Kathy'], "Steve's House")
```

which I use a wrapper class around to add extensibility:

```
>>> class Party(namedtuple('Party', ['guests', 'location'])):
    ...
```

but with two differences. I would like the fields to be mutable, and I would like inheritance to work. (Right now I don't think there's a way to have one namedtuple inherit from another).

I've heard about `types.SimpleNamespace`, but I don't think it allows positional arguments in creation (someone correct me if I'm wrong). I like namedtuples because they keep me from having to write `__init__`, `__repr__`, and `__eq__`, all of which I need for my use case.

What is important to me: built-in implementations of `__init__`, `__repr__` and `__eq__` so I don't have to write them myself. I'm going to need many (30+) of these class definitions, and some of them will have many (15+) fields.

What isn't important to me (right now): memory efficiency. I don't plan to have more than five hundred instances of these at any one time.

I'm thinking of rolling my own, but want to make sure I'm not re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Would using the `__slots__` attribute in `class Party` suffice?

Comment: When you say *"very like `namedtuple`"*, what *precise* qualities are you looking for? If it's a space issue, then @chepner's suggestion to use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) is a good one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes, good question. I want `__eq__`, `__repr__` and `__init__`. It doesn't need to be hashable or to subclass `tuple`.

Comment: @EliRose so size *isn't* an issue? Why don't you just write a regular class?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I'm going to have 50 of these, some with many fields, and don't want to rewrite the same `__repr__` and `__init__` logic for every one of them. So, the amount of code it takes to define a class is important to me.

Comment: @EliRose 50 *classes*, or 50 *instances*? As it stands, it is **profoundly unclear** what you're asking for; please edit the question to clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve generally and why you can't just write a regular superclass specifically. You could always look at [the source code for `namedtuple`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l234) and borrow what you need from that.

Comment: You're right, thanks for helping me realize how to communicate this better.  The 50 refers to class definitions.

Comment: Python isn't designed for type checking, so it does not really make very much sense (in some cases it can make, I admit) to make own classes for these lightweight data structures.  How about just using [an arbitrary data type](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/579092-data-a-class-for-arbitrary-data/)?

Comment: @Alfe: Looks interesting, but I'd like to be able to specify my fields in the class definition and throw an error (as `namedtuple` does) if you try to instantiate without providing all of them.

Comment: You could probably achieve what you want by writing a single metaclass that provides the dynamic implementation of `__eq__` etc, then each of your actual classes would be instances of that, which just provide the names of that class's attributes.

Comment: @TomDalton: That's what I was going to do, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't re-inventing the wheel. (There seems to be a lot of coding involved in e.g. making sure subclassing works correctly).

Comment: FWIW, there's a simple way to [combine namedtuples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28942143/4014959). But I guess that's not really relevant here, since you need mutability.

Comment: Which [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) features _do_ you actually need? Eg, do you need numerical indexing & the ability to iterate?

Comment: @PM2Ring: I need nothing except the implementations of `__init__`, `__repr__` and `__eq__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone finding this question in 2022, the most appropriate Python feature that achieves this is now [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Party:
    guests: List[str]
    location: str
```

Answer (score 1):

For a problem you need 50 class definitions for less than five hundred instances . . . in total ?  Maybe you should re-consider the problem and find a very different approach ?   Tried looking at dictionaries ?

```
item1 = {'party':'easter', 'guests': ['john', fred','kathy'], 'location':'here'}
```

Than you need only the standard python dict-class and can easy test field presence, add fields and so on, it has init, repr and eq.

Or provide some more information on the problem.